# React unable to pass paramaeter

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass the id parameter to the showdesc function but it is not getting passed
can anyone help please

app.js has a router

```
 <Router>
              <Route exact path="/">
                {/*sets the header to display searchbar*/}
                <Header isSearchBar={true} handleOnChange={change} />
                <ShowCards cards={movies} lastMovieRef={lastMovieElement}/>
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/:id">
                {/*sets the header to not display searchbar*/}
                <Header isSearchBar={false} handleOnChange={change} />
                <ShowDesc/>
              </Route>
          </Router>
```

showdeck.js

```
 import * as React from 'react'
    import './ShowDesc.css'
    import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
    function ShowDesc(){
        const [card,setCard] =useState();
        const {handle} = useParams();
        return (
        <p>handle</p>
        )
    }
```

The parameter id is not getting passed to the showDesc functions can anyone help me passing it out

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `id` instead of `handle` since the param is the id, and secondly you should put the id in the HTML with curly-braces (`<p>{id}</p>`) to show the value, like this:

```js
const {id} = useParams();
return (
  <p>{id}</p>
)
```

Or:

```js
const params = useParams();
return (
  <p>{params.id}</p>
)
```

You can see more documentation in the react router dom [homepage](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams).